# Checking if input value is not empty or default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm look for an elegant way to check if input value is not empty and not default.

For example let's say we have input with value `Username`, this is a default value, and once the user clicks on this input field `Username` would be deleted so user could enter what he wants. Just to make it clear this is how it would look when the page is loaded:

`<input type="text" class="defaultValue" value="Username" />`

Now by default this field would never be empty, unless user would do something to make it empty, so just to make sure i need to check for both things. The way i would do this is very simple:

```
if($(".defaultValue").val().length == 0 || $(".defaultValue").val() == "Username")
   alert("Please enter your username");
```

So this works, but looks ugly as hell. And usually i need to deal with huge forms so my code gets really ugly and hard to manage because of this, any way to improve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use placeholder attribute?

Comment: @undefined I have never heard about that attribute.

Comment: @undefined Just took a look at documentation and it says `Note: The placeholder attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.` And i need to support IE 9.

Comment: @undefined—placeholders aren't supported by all browsers. But yes, that's a better solution.

Comment: There are many plugins for placeholder attribute, one of them is this https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim, it's only 3kb.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
if (this.value == '' || this.value == this.defaultValue) {
  // value is empty or is default value
}
```

Comment: So what is difference ? only removing 0 can make it pretty ?

Comment: Well this definitely looks better.

Comment: @Garray—removing the unnecessary jQuery cruft and using direct property access means it's not only way less code, but probably about 20 times faster.

Comment: @ RobG Well now i am agree with you as there was no reference in Answer that it makes code fast i raised the comment

Comment: I'm accepting this answer even thou i chose to use `undefined` provided jQuery plugin, but this is also a very good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing a helper function to do this check for you.

```
var isEmptyOrDefault = function(field, default) {
    var value = $(field).val();
    return (value.length === 0 || value === default);
};
```

So you can use it:

```
if (isEmptyOrDefault($('.defaultValue'), 'Username')) {
    alert("Please enter your username");
}
```

Comment: In your example, you pass the `field` argument as a jQuery object, but then inside `isEmptyOrDefault()` you have `$(field).val()` which would result in `$($('.defaultValue')).val()` which is not going to work.

Comment: @undefined huh, so it does. Well, sweetamylase is lucky that jQuery is so forgiving :)

Comment: @idrumgood jQuery will always check if the variable passed to it is an instance of jQuery. The example is just for demonstrating that introducing a helper function could keep the rest of the code logic more manageable.